# How to remove D&D uploaded files from the Github?

Tags: github

I uploaded files to the GitHub issues tracker with Drag&Drop, but I want to remove them from there and that cloud hosting server(cloud.githubusercontent.com).

Possible?

Comment: 3rd question like this today. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git

Comment: @agilob I do not think so. The correct tag is not "git" but "github". Do you know the difference between "git" and "github"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Navigate to the file in webbrowser and find [trash] icon on top right hand side of the file content.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. But, there is no trash icon in a issue page. All I want to do is to remove images in a issue page.(ex. I want to remove vim-hjkl-game screenshots in https://github.com/shouh/images/issues/1 )

Comment: @shouh I don't think there is a way of removing images from githubs cnd. You can try requesting removal from github. You can remove the images by editing the post and removing markdown of the image.